# Get all html on page except for ones that have a certain class

Tags: jquery, html, export, checked

My goal is to get all the HTML on a page except those which checkboxes are unchecked and post it to a script.

I do this by having checkboxes with a value which is a class on an element. For example my checkbox is in a row on a table and that  ...

All the content I want is inside #page_content. As the content isn't aware of it's container - that is the checkbox doesn't know it's inside of the table so can't wrap  around it, I figured it's easier to get everything on the page and just remove the elements that are unchecked. That way my markup is correct.

I am using jQuery to do this, but I don't know how to approach it correctly. The way I have in mind is to get all the unchecked checkboxes and store their values into a variable 'unchecked'.

I have an outerHTML() function that can get me the element and it's html.

Then I

```
$('#export').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var uc, unchecked = [], html;
        $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function() {
            unchecked.push("." + $(this).val());
        });
        uc = unchecked.join(',') + ",.actions,input,button,.btn";
        console.log(uc);
        $('#page_content').find('*').not(uc).each(function() {
            html += $(this).outerHTML();
        });
        console.log(html);
        // $('#export-data').val(html);
        // console.log($('#export-data').val());
    });
```

Then by the end of it I have this string of all the HTML.

Update: Worked a bit more on it, I get something but it's mixed tags. Also I want to stript out inputs and buttons and other classes so I think I'm doing it right but the output has many duplicates. Hmmm....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok using my method I found it clearer and more jquery-ish :)

```
var filter, html, el, unchecked = [], additional, elements;
$('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function() {
    unchecked.push("#" + $(this).val());
});
// We remove checkboxes, cb colums, inputs, etc
additional = ".actions,input,button,.btn,textarea,.cb";
if (unchecked.length) {
    filter = unchecked.join(',') + "," + additional;
} else {
    filter = additional;
}
var $elements = $('#page_content').clone();
$elements.find(filter).remove();
html = $elements.outerHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is an example of how you can do it. in the example it will return all elements except the one of class green.

code is ready to be copy pasted and run

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
    DIV{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .black{
        background:black;
    }
    .yellow{
        background:yellow;
    }
    .red{
        background:red;
    }
    .green{
        background:green;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="1" class="yellow"></div>
        <div id="2" class="black"></div>
        <div id="3" class="red"></div>
        <div id="4" class="green"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function (){
        var elements = $('*');
        var filterClass = 'green';
        elements = $.grep(elements,function(elementOfArray, indexInArray){
            clas = $(elementOfArray).attr('class');
            if(typeof(clas) ===  'undefined'){
                console.log('undef');
                return elementOfArray
            }
            if(clas.indexOf(filterClass) == -1){
                return elementOfArray;
            }
        });
        console.log(elements);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I updated the original post to give you more of an idea. I need to strip some other things out. Maybe find('*') isn't the best thing to use?

Comment: i just used (*) as an example, all you need to do is get the elements in an array and parse it through the grep method. i am unsure of your html so i cant help you with that

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to grep out a list of things - inputs, classes, textareas etc.

Comment: you would be filtering on the class of the elements.